# Can I use "lardy-dardy" to describe a man's gay lisp and gesture?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, colloquialisms

Can I use "*lardy-dardy*" to describe a man's gay lisp and gesture?  If this is not OK, I have three more questions.

1. How else can I ever use *lardy-dardy*?
2. Which word should I be using instead?
3. Is there a new generation of buzzwords to use?

Comment: If this is not OK ... what?

Comment: Gay men have lisps?

Comment: @tchrist I mentioned this in my original answer, but edited it out later because it wasn't part of the answer. It used to be (Even I remember it.) a common stereotype that many gay men had lisps. It's not nearly as common now. Similarly, I did want to mention that not all gay men are camp, but that was also unnecessary, so I didn't even think about including it.

Comment: You shouldn't be writing about such things if you have to ask such questions. This only displays your insensitivity to issues of stereotyping.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in providing context -- even if not seen to be entirely relevant. No need for discussing it if it's not relevant, anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest that you re-write your question on these lines: (I guess you are new around here, and this, just 2c.) Here goes: "*lardy-dardy* (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lardy-dardy) is one phrase I am trying to use in the sense of the kind of lisp and gesture supposedly associated with some GLBTs. Even the UrbanDictionary entry (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lardy%20dardy) does not speak of any such thing as I meant. Is there an alternate, similar phrase suitable for my contextual use?"

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, "lardy-dardy" only really refers to being extraordinarily elegant. I believe you may be looking for "flamboyant" or "camp". "Camp" is a modern word to describe stereotypically gay behavior.

Comment: Well, no, "camp" isn't that at all. And "flamboyant" is generic. And you shouldn't be discussing these things if you don't understand them better than that. It's unacceptable and insensitive to suggest that there even should be a term for "stereotypically" gay behavior. You're talking about caricatures. Would you want someone to come up with a word to describe the "stereotypically whatever-you-are type of behavior?" Wouldn't you resent that?

Comment: Now, now, @JohnM.Landsberg -- remember not everyone is knowledgeable enough to be sensitive enough. This place helps people *learn* things, so it's okay I suppose. :) I bet you didn't know or understand all this not long ago yourself, just as anyone else.

Comment: @Kris That would be my point, Kris. They need to learn. And I think my comments, although admittedly couched in chiding tones, are part of the process of teaching them what they have to learn. But allow me to expand on one point: Flatly stating that a particular word definitively "means" something in particular, and not even qualifying it as "possible," "one of many," nor a matter of the writer's personal opinion, is, I feel, inappropriate. Yes, we may all be guilty at times, but I think users need to be reminded not to presume to such authority when they have no real basis for it.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg First of all, I *myself* am gay. Secondly, *camp* is used to describe it these days. I may not be camp myself, but I do know enough to not be insensitive. I was merely providing as straightforward an answer (that the individual who asked the question would understand due to differences in the times we grew up in) as I could. Please do try to not assume next time. I do know that there are camp heterosexual men. Nevertheless, in the questioner's time of growing up, such behavior would likely lead to someone being identified as homosexual no matter what.

Comment: Kudos to you for being willing to state that. In my defense, I refer you to my motives in saying what I said, which I hope were clearly in the interests of truth, justice, and you know... :) (Quoting Woody Allen in, I believe, _Annie Hall_: "Right. I know. I'm a bigot. But for _the left_!")

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg I completely understand.

Answer (score 1):

There's a possibility that there really are (were?) two ideas here.

*Lardy* by itself means *grand*, *rich*, *swell*.
*Lardy-dardy*, OTH, *affected*, *effeminate*.

*A Dictionary of slang and Colloquial English*, John Stephen Farmer, William Ernest Henley (c) [GoogleBooks Preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=lUYVAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA261&dq=define%20%22lardy-dardy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oQNlUdanJoS8rAed-oHIDQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ)